# The post->success->data variable is empty

Tags: jquery, post

I tried sending some data like so:

```
<form action="http://www.someurl.com/something.php" id="login">
    <input type="textbox" id="UserName" value="user">
    <input type="textbox" id="Password" value="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


            $('form#login').submit(function() {
               $.post($('form#login').attr('action'), $('form#login').serialize(), function(data) {
                   $('#result').html(data+'222')
               });
               return false;
            });



</script>
```

Now, the value of #result div change to 222... that is: the post was successful but for some reason there is no data, and when I go directly to something.php and post manually, it does bring back data (am I mistaken or does the post(success(data)) variable returns the whole page returned after you post something? if so, how could it be?)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your request type?

Try this...

```
$('form#login').submit(function() {
               $.post($('form#login').attr('action'), $('form#login').serialize(), function(data) {
                   $('#result').html(data.success+'222')
               });
               return false;
            },'json');
```

Have your script out put this as a test:
{"success" : "some data" }

Comment: oh I realized that the page is getting another call for GET and has a check for headers so I can't get the data from outside the server...
any ideas about that? some sort of simulation ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  As far as a simulation just create a php script called fortest.php, and have it say this:

{ "success" : "this worked!" }

I have written a bit here on creating standardized output for jQuery ajax here:
http://geektasking.com/?p=50